# Use . in a method registered with LuaInterface

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lua, luainterface

I'm integrating LuaInterface into a c# program using LuaInterface. I want to be able to write scripts that can access C# methods in the program.

The methods that it is accessing are in separate "subsystems" and I wanted to have the Lua method define the subsystem, then the method using . as a separator.
e.g. SubsystemName.MethodName

but this throws an exception when I try to register the method. I've changed it to _ and it works perfectly. Is there anyway to get it working with .? The program has other interfaces for calling these methods like JSON-RPC via HTTP and these use the . notation so would like it to be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your methods using `_` as a separator in your .NET code, e.g. `SubsystemName_MethodName`. Then create a simple Lua module, that does roughly the following:

```
local YourClass = luanet.import_type("Your.Binding.Class")

SubsystemName = {} -- create a global table
SubsystemName.MethodName = YourClass.SubsystemName_MethodName
```

This will allow you to use `SubsystemName.MethodName` in Lua.

Instead of doing it manually (which can be tedious and error-prone), you can use a code generator that creates the Lua code from a list of classes/methods.

Comment: This worked, I already had code registered all the methods. I think you misunderstood me though. The program running is written in C#. I wanted it to be able to run Lua scripts where those scripts have access to .net methods. I'm using the LuaInterface library to do this. Your code works though so I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Member names cannot contain `.` in .NET.

Comment: I know, that isn't what I wanted. In .Net the subsystems are different classes. I just wanted the call in Lua to use . like I do in Json. The system parses that to figure out which class the method is in.